# Get an item from inside json with php code

Tags: php, arrays

I can show the FactorDate item with the following code.

```
$response=json_decode($response->getBody());
foreach($response as $product)
{
    echo $product->FactorDate;
}
```

but I can not show the Price item. please guide me.

[
{
"CustomerCode": 101,
"FactorNumber": 53,
"FactorDate": 14010201,
"FactorDetails": [
{
"ProductCode": 21901,
"Count": 15,
"Price": 96000000,
"VisitorID": 0
}
]
}
]

Comment: *but I can not show the Price item* what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON that you had provided looks like price is a part of an array within FactorDetails. Meaning that if you want to get the price you will likely have to do something like:

`$product->FactorDetails[0]->Price`

Or put into your example, something like this will display both Date and Price:

```php
$response=json_decode($response->getBody());
foreach($response as $product)
{
    echo $product->FactorDate;
    echo $product->FactorDetails[0]->Price;
}
```

That should work.

For future reference, you could use a tool like this JSON viewer to see a more readable version of your JSON which can be super helpful when dealing with formatting issues like this one:

https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. It was done correctly with your formula

Comment: @samanshirmohammadi see if there is a reason why FactorDetails is an array. If it's something you can help, I would try to turn FactorDetails into an object itself so you can just do something like `$product->FactorDetails->Price`. I feel like it's a bit hacky referring to the first object of the array by doing `[0]`.

Comment: I'm doing my job exactly with your code and it is done correctly. Thank you